# JWT default GET action limitation?

Tags: jwt

I've successfully used cookies before and I'd like to begin using JWT.  My biggest question is how to pass your token to a website during the **initial GET operation**, for example when a user **types your domain into their address bar** or clicks on a link from some other website like google.

When using cookies for example, if you type stackoverflow.com into your web browser, the **persistent cookie is sent to the website** which seamlessly allows your own stackoverflow session to be **automatically authorized**.

I am aware that I can programatically pass my JWT token via a javascript GET through the HTTP headers but how do you pass the token when a visitor types in your URL into their web browser?

**Possible solution #1**

My thoughts have been to have javascript code check if 'authorized'.  If not, check for a JWT token in local storage.  If found, redirect to the same address.  The problem of course would be that there is no way to pass the token during a redirect.

**Possible solution #2**

Similar to above but not issuing a redirect, I would update the current page to reflect the 'authorized' state.

**Possible solution #3**

Use a permanent cookie containing the JWT token.  I am thinking that this 3rd option would be the best.  If I did this, there would be no need to pass the JWT via an HTTP header.

Comment: Do you want to pass jwt token as 'Authorization' header?

Comment: @RaghuSodha, yes.  Let's say that the user authenticated yesterday and decides to visit your site today.  Just like facebook or stackoverflow, I want my 'authorization' to persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about this for a few days, read up on JWT and here are my conclusions for avoiding JWT in my particular case:

1. No easy way to **authorize a user** who opens their browser and types in your website.  With cookies, your server immediately knows how to respond to this **headerless GET** request.
2. No way to easily **change the JWT token signature**.  All users are immediately affected by such a change, essentially forcing everyone to authenticate again.
3. No way to easily **invalidate a specific JWT token**.  The best you can do is to maintain and check a banned signature list on the server.  This of course would require a centralized or distributed server method almost identical to a cookie session management system.  This would force a coupling between the token and the server, no longer stateless as intended by JWT.

SUMMARY

Cookie management requires more server infrastructure but you have much greater session control.  State is seamless (in the case of #1 above).  You can instantly invalidate state.  For example, the user can log out (deleting the session at the server level) or the session can be instantly banned by an administrator by simply deleting the session.

I also see the benefits to JWS:

1. no need to **hit the db or cache system** when authorizing.
2. **simple authorization** between multiple servers having the secret key.
3. **simple authorization**, no session management programming and no db session state storage required.

...but the drawbacks stated previously are too great for my particular needs.